# How to write manager class to set default attribute value for models while retrieval/filtering in Django queries?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-managers

```py
class StudentModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super(StudentModelManager, self)
            .get_queryset()
            .filter(is_deleted=False)
        )


class StudentDetails(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = StudentModelManager()
```

I have four entries in database 2 with `is_deleted=False` and 2 with `is_deleted=True`.

Because of `StudentModelManager` in `StudentDetails` model I could not retrieve records from database for `is_deleted=True`.

I want to make sure that the default parameter while retrieving should be `is_deleted=False`, but when explicit parameter is given like
`is_deleted=True`, it should return objects with that value.

Actual Entries in db **without applying** `StudentModelManager` to `StudentDetails` model are :

```
>>> StudentDetails.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<StudentDetails: StudentDetails object (27)>, <StudentDetails StudentDetails object (29)>, <StudentDetails: StudentDetails object (30)>, <StudentDetails: StudentDetails object (28)>]>
```

Entries retrieved from db **with applying** `StudentModelManager` to `StudentDetails` model with `is_deleted=False`:

```
>>> StudentDetails.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<StudentDetails: StudentDetails object (27)>, <StudentDetails StudentDetails object (29)>]>
```

Now see the actual issues, Not able to retrieve entries with `is_deleted=True`

```
>>> StudentDetails.objects.filter(is_deleted=True)
<QuerySet []>
```

**Expected output** is:

```
>>> StudentDetails.objects.filter(is_deleted=True)
<QuerySet [<StudentDetails: StudentDetails object (28)>, <StudentDetails StudentDetails object (30)>]>
```

How can this achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements, it would be better to create a different manager to return StudentDetails which is deleted. If you change the default manager, the query for deleted objects would be impossible as the base QuerySet is filtered.

The use of different managers [is suggested by Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset). ("You can attach as many Manager() instances to a model as you’d like. This is a non-repetitive way to define common “filters” for your models.").

With that in mind, you could use the following:

```py
class StudentModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super(StudentModelManager, self)
            .get_queryset()
            .filter(is_deleted=False)
        )


class StudentDetails(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = models.Manager()
    existing_objects = StudentModelManager()
```

In the case of getting existing objects, you can use
`StudentDetails.existing_objects.all()`
In the case of query deleted objects, you can use
`StudentDetails.objects.filter(is_deleted=True)`.